# Sanity check: how are packages and modules are meant to be used together?

Tags: java

Prior to Java 9, I had assumed that packages were a way to promote/enforce modularization of code and to solve the namespacing problem. Packages actually do a really poor problem of solving the latter (`com.popkernel.myproject.Employee myEmployee = new com.popkernel.myproject.Employee();`, ugh) so I primarily focused on the former benefit.

And while packages do a very poor job at enforcing modularity, I've found them quite effective at promoting modularity. "What package does this class belong in?" has always been an illuminating question, and I appreciate that Java forces me to ask myself it.

But now Java 9 modules are here and they enforce the modularity problem better than packages. In fact, you could compose a new project entirely out of modules where each module wraps a single package.

Of course, modules are a LOT of extra boilerplate compared to packages, not to mention the quirk that unlike packages, it is impossible to tell what module a class belongs to just by examining its .java file.

So going forward my plan for using packages and modules together is: as I'm writing code, group related concepts into packages. Then, if I decide I want to distribute the code I'm working on, formalize it into a module.

Is that a sane way to utilize those concepts in tandem?

Comment: I don't understand how packaging does a poor job solving the namespacing problem. I think they tend to do a rather good job.

Comment: The problem is packages should be hierarchical. For example, I should be able to refer to com.foo.popkernel.myproject.Bar by writing import com.foo.popkernel.* and then I could use myproject.Bar as the type name.

Answer (score 1):

> **Is that a sane way to utilize those concepts in tandem?**

**Yes**, kind of. Though there are other benefits that you can gain from modularising your code such as *Reliable configuration*, *Strong encapsulation*, *Increased Readability* etc.

> > So going forward my plan for using packages and modules together is:
> >     as I'm writing code, group related concepts into packages. Then, if I
> >     decide I want to distribute the code I'm working on, formalize it into
> >     a module.

A quick question you can ask yourself is that while you would be using modules, and as you would *group related concepts into packages*, eventually how do you group related packages then?

The answer that could match up to the reason is the introduction of a new kind of Java program component - ***[Modules](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#defining-modules)***

> A module is a named, self-describing collection of code and data. Its
>   code is *organized as a **set** of packages* containing types, i.e.,
>   Java classes and interfaces; its data includes resources and other
>   kinds of static information.

Until now such collections were primarily targeted as JAR files, that were distributed to be consumed as dependencies/libraries within other, but they are becoming legacy formats and differ quite a bit with modules. In one of my recent answers to [Java 9 - What is the difference between "Modules" and "JAR" files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46514113/1746118) I have tried to detail the differences.